# Items not updating in .NET Backend using UpdateAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently writing a Mobile Service backend for a C# Universal app I'm updating. Everything works except for the ability to update items in a table. The patch function in the controller executes without throwing an exception and the push notification it sends when completed works, however nothing actually gets updated.

My models and snippets of the controller:

https://gist.github.com/coreyRalli/058075d810ac56b3b6e2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.